# Qlik Sense Load Editor. All the sudden field not found when using IF statement

Tags: load, qliksense

The script runs okay when just the field name is specified.

But when using IF statement, it gives error that `if field not found`.

What is the issue and how to fix it?

```
"IF(ISNULL(mcdRegion),'',(mcdRegion)) as [Region]"
```

Comment: Is there are reason you have double quotes `"` around your expression? Is that just to format it here for StackOverflow or is that how it is in your script? Because Qlik considers double quotes to be one of the types of **enclosures**. You can identify fields/table names with square backets `[]`, double quotes `""`, or backticks ``. So Qlik could be reading `"IF(...` as the start of a field name because of that double quote.

Comment: Also check out the `Coalesce()` function, as it achieves the same thing but more concisely.

Answer (score 1):

I think for the field name in your 'other' condition you swap out the `()` for `[]` or leave open since the field doesn't have spaces. So it would be:

```
IF(ISNULL(mcdRegion),'',[mcdRegion]) as [Region]
```

or

```
IF(ISNULL(mcdRegion),'',mcdRegion) as [Region]
```